# Structure of query does not match function result type - Returned type Timestamp with time Zone

Tags: postgresql

I have a function called spGetDeviceDetails. This takes in a text argument and returns a query from a table called Device.

This table is defined as follows:

**Device table DDL**

```
create table device
(
    deviceid              uuid not null
        constraint pk__device__49e123311461d246
            primary key,
    serialnumber          varchar(255),
    productcode           varchar(255),
    description           varchar(255),
    softwareversion       varchar(255),
    build                 varchar(255),
    builddate             timestamp with time zone,
    assigned              boolean,
    groupid               uuid
        constraint fkdevice951246
            references groups,
    updateddatetime       timestamp with time zone,
    restartpointerno      integer,
    deviceconnectionindex integer
        constraint fkdevice_deviceconnectiontype
            references deviceconnectiontype,
    organisationid        uuid
        constraint fk_device_organisation_organisationid
            references organisation
);

alter table device
    owner to postgres;
```

My function is defined as follows

**spGetDeviceDetails**

```
CREATE  FUNCTION spGetDeviceDetails(SerialNumber2 text)
    RETURNS TABLE(ProductCode text, SerialNumber text, Description text, SoftwareVersion text, Build text, BuildDate timestamp with time zone, Assigned Boolean)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    #variable_conflict use_column
BEGIN

            RETURN QUERY
            SELECT d.ProductCode ::text,
                   d.SerialNumber ::text,
                   d.Description ::text,
                   d.SoftwareVersion ::text,
                   d.BuildDate :: timestamp with time zone,
                   d.assigned :: Boolean

            FROM  dbo.Device d
            WHERE
                    d.serialnumber = SerialNumber2;

END
$$;
```

When i run this as follows:

```
select * from spGetDeviceDetails('876302')
```

I get the following error message:

```
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] [42804] ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] Detail: Returned type timestamp with time zone does not match expected type text in column 5.
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] Where: SQL statement "SELECT d.ProductCode ::text,
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.SerialNumber ::text,
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.Description ::text,
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.SoftwareVersion ::text,
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.BuildDate :: timestamp with time zone,
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.assigned :: Boolean
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] FROM  dbo.Device d
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] WHERE
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] d.serialnumber = SerialNumber2"
[2023-11-02 10:43:17] PL/pgSQL function spgetdevicedetails(text) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
```

So as you can this refers to column 5 which is BuildDate
But i have defined BuildDate as data type : timestamp with time zone ... same as its definition in the table Device

So why is this not working?

Comment: You forgot `d.build` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz...I didnt see that. Now it works ! thank you